# how to automate interviews

Tags: davinci-resolve, script

I have many short interviews (50). All are shot same condition and the same settings of cam.

My question is does DaVinci Resolve have some sort of templating, scripting to automatically apply my lut, prepend intro clip, then append ending clip, and export?

Answer (score 1):

Resolve supports scripting with Python, though you’ll need to write your own script. Fusion, included with Resolve, supports scripting with both Python and Lua. There aren’t really templates, *per se*, but you could probably hack something together by saving a fusion composition as your template and driving the file selection with scripts. I don’t think the render queue is very well supported by the scripting API though, there’s a steep learning curve, and not a lot of documentation.  If you’re just bookending a list of trimmed interviews with static, boilerplate intro/outro, FFMPEG would be more direct.  But yes, it would be possible.

*edit* Feb 2010

Resolve 17 Beta has added some features which make this process easier, including the ability to execute scripts on render completion, and Fusion Effects templates for the Edit page.